# Error to start press button "start"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Folks!

I lean C# and I'm using the book "Head First C# - 3rd Edition.". But my first example not work. My first program successfully build, then I am press button "start" program crashing.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;

// Документацию по шаблону элемента "Основная страница" см. по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234237

namespace Save_The_Humans
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Основная страница, которая обеспечивает характеристики, являющимися общими для большинства приложений.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Save_The_Humans.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Заполняет страницу содержимым, передаваемым в процессе навигации. Также предоставляется любое сохраненное состояние
        /// при повторном создании страницы из предыдущего сеанса.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="navigationParameter">Значение параметра, передаваемое
        /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> при первоначальном запросе этой страницы.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="pageState">Словарь состояния, сохраненного данной страницей в ходе предыдущего
        /// сеанса. Это значение будет равно NULL при первом посещении страницы.</param>
        protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Сохраняет состояние, связанное с данной страницей, в случае приостановки приложения или
        /// удаления страницы из кэша навигации. Значения должны соответствовать требованиям сериализации
        /// <see cref="SuspensionManager.SessionState"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pageState">Пустой словарь, заполняемый сериализуемым состоянием.</param>
        protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddEnemy();
        }

        private void AddEnemy()
        {
            ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
            enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100),
                random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
            playArea.Children.Add(enemy);

        }

        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }

       }
}
```

VS 2012 for Windows 8 said me: "'maxValue' must be greater than zero."

What did I do wrong and how can I fix this bag?

Link source code and VS project: https://dropmefiles.com/RmCbZ

Screen error message:

[image]

Comment: Error message doesn't matches with posted code. Post the relevant code.

Comment: @Rahul, this code success build, BUT during make(play) program i see a error. Understand me or no? Sorry my English.

Comment: I add screen with error message from VS 2012 Express for Windows 8.

Comment: Please have a look at the chat again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100)`. When you are using `.Next(maxvalue)` with just one value it has to be a positive one.
*Additional information: When using it like `.Next(minvalue, maxvalue)` it is ok having two negative values.*

> maxValue
>   Type: System.Int32
>
> The exclusive upper bound of the random number to be generated. maxValue must be greater than or equal to 0. [(From here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

What you can do to resolve this problem:

- Make sure that `playArea.ActualHeight` is greater than 100. (set a breakpoint and check the value of this variable)
- Are you sure you have to substract 100? (Depends on your scenario)
- You could use `random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100, /*maxvalue*/)`

**Edit:** I took the time to scan through the according chapter of this book and noticed, that the default dimensions of a `Canvas` (called `playArea`) is 100x100 and nothing tells you to increase the size... According to your original problem I assume that you accidently made it even smaller. So you could try going back to the designer and increase the size of `playArea` (and maybe the whole window).

Comment: Thank you very much! When I use  random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100, 101) button "start" do not work. I am not understand, why code in books work at the author, but not work at me? It is sad.

Comment: Did you do *everything* beforehand *exactly* as shown? Did you skip anything? Did you modify anything? Did you leave anything as default, even if the book told you to modify something?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, Yes. I checked, but possible bug.

Comment: Do you see a rectangle with a gradient from purple to black? (This might sound stupid but I don't have Windows 8 and therefor I can't open it, but I tried to rebuild it and I don't see this rectangle)

Comment: @Jibbow, Yes, only to me gradient from white to black.

Comment: One minuet, I make screen.

Comment: @Jibbow, [screen](https://habrastorage.org/files/ed4/09c/146/ed409c14634d42a885383ecbba660afb.PNG).  This window appears after concealed and opened the window.

Comment: Yes! Change your XAML: `<Canvas x:Name="playArea" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="200">`

Comment: I changing, thanks. There is no error, but program not correct :). Thank you very much, I try again reeds books and make project with VS.

Comment: @Jibbow, You have skype,viber and other? Go to chatting and be friend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89517/discussion-between-jibbow-and-dkvl).